# How can I get 'fire and forget' behaviour from c# console code to web api

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

Check the below block of code. I need fire and forget behavior while calling sendMail method (i.e. while calling api). With this block of code I'm getting TaskCancelledException sometimes. Please help

```
private void ProcessMails()
{
    while(true)
    {
        var mailsToBeProcessed = getAllMailsToBeProcessed(alreadySent,      numOfMailsToBeProcessed);

        freach(var mail in Mails)
        {
            sendMail("mailsendingApiUrl", mail)
            alreadySent++;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }
}

private async void sendMail(string apiEndPoint, MailContent mailContent)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
         await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiEndPoint, mailContent.ContentId);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you return `void` from async method, you *do* have fire & forget, just put the `sendMail` between a try, catch and you'll never hear from it again. (whether it's good practice or not is another issue of course)

Comment: why are you using `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi  I'm not supposed to send too many mails per min. And if so I endup keeping mail server busy. That's why.

Comment: you can wait for each process to be finished before sending next request by using `Wait()`. see my answer below for code.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void ProcessMails()
{
 while(true)
 {
  var mailsToBeProcessed = getAllMailsToBeProcessed(alreadySent, numOfMailsToBeProcessed);

   foreach(var mail in mailsToBeProcessed)
   {
     sendMail("mailsendingApiUrl", mail).Wait();
     alreadySent++;
   }
  }
}

private async Task sendMail(string apiEndPoint, MailContent mailContent)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
         await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiEndPoint, mailContent.ContentId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Tried configureawait with false but no use. But I didn't tried with .wait(). Let me try

Comment: sendMail("mailsendingApiUrl", mail).Wait(); this line has an error. It is not recognizing Wait() method. Showing in red.  We cannot apply this for return type void methods it seems.

Comment: yes you need to remove the return type `void` and make it a `Task`. I've updated the answer.